# Valid inputs and use animation untill page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, validation

I need to validate filled inputs and on submit if all inputs are valid show load animation till next page will shown. I can check for validation one by one, but do not know how to collect them all in one. Maybe there are more simple way to check inputs validation? Also I did all validations inside inputs in code below.
 **Here is my inputs type which i need to validate and on success show load animation until page refresh to another page:**

```html
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formz" >
  <div>
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text" onkeydown="return keyDown.call(this,event)" onchange="value = value.replace(/^\s+/,'')" pattern=".{3,20}" name="name" required>
  </div>
  
  
  <div>
    <label>Surname: </label>
    <input type="text" onkeydown="return keyDown.call(this,event)" onchange="value = value.replace(/^\s+/,'')" pattern=".{3,20}" name="surname" required>
  </div>
  
  
  <div>
    <label>Unic Number: </label>
    <input type="text" onkeydown="return keyDown.call(this,event)" onchange="value = value.replace(/^\s+/,'')" pattern=".{7,7}" maxlength='7' name="unicnumb" required />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Select:</label>
    <select name="select" id="select" required> 
     <OPTION VALUE="0" selected disabled >Select</OPTION>
     <OPTION VALUE="1">Select1</OPTION>
     <OPTION VALUE="2">Select2</OPTION>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>phone: </label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="+XXX(XX) XXX-XX-XX" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="epoct">E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}" class="form-control input-sm" name="epoct" id="epoct" required>
  </div>
  
  <button type="submit" name="button" id="button">Done</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the outline for how I've handled successive form validation with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#button" ).submit(function( event ) {
        if ( /* validation fails for first form element */ ) {
            // stop form submission
            event.preventDefault();
            // display an error message
            $( "#firstFormFieldId" ).append("<span>Incorrect entry</span>");
            // break out of function to ensure validation continues if and only if this condition is met
            return false;
        }
        if ( /* validation fails for second form element */ ) {
            // stop form submission
            event.preventDefault();
            // display an error message
            $( "#secondFormFieldId" ).append("<span>Incorrect entry</span>");
            // break out of function to ensure validation continues if and only if this condition is met
            return false;
        }
        if ( /* validation fails for third form element */ ) {
            // stop form submission
            event.preventDefault();
            // display an error message
            $( "#thirdFormFieldId" ).append("<span>Incorrect entry</span>");
            // break out of function to ensure validation continues if and only if this condition is met
            return false;
        }
        // ... repeat for as many form fields that need validation

        // if all validation criteria are met, you can deploy loading animation here :)
        /* loading animation goes here */
    });
});
```

You can probably already imagine some variations to this template. For instance, rather than appending the `<span>`s, you could add empty `<span>`s intended to contain the error messages to your HTML. If an error message needs to be displayed, you then use jQuery to add the text of the error message to the corresponding `<span>`. The actual implementation will depend on you, but this style has worked well for me.